# How to concate List of objects having same key attribute

Tags: java, arrays, spring-mvc, arraylist

**I'm trying to Concat custom Objects if particular key attribute of objects matches**

I'm getting data in below format.

> List is like this.

```
 Data[
{batchNo: "1212", location: "12bbn", qty: "123", rawMaterialId: "6743"},
{batchNo: "1213", location: "12nmn", qty: "300", rawMaterialId: "6743"},
{batchNo: "1241", location: "vbv2", qty: "123", rawMaterialId: "9179"},
{batchNo: "1251", location: "fdsfds", qty: "244", rawMaterialId: "9179"},
{batchNo: "1233", location: "cvcvbc", qty: "200", rawMaterialId: "9169"},
{batchNo: "1266", location: "bnbn", qty: "600", rawMaterialId: "9935"}
]
```

I'm trying concat them based on a particular key attribute i.e ( rawMaterialId ).

for example, if rawMaterialId= 6743 of index[0] matches index[1] both needs to be concatenated.

> Expected List

```
    Data[
      {batchNo: "1212 , 1213", location: "12bbn , 12nmn", qty: "123 , 300", rawMaterialId: "6743"},
{batchNo: "1241,1251", location: "vbv2 , fdsfds", qty: "123,244",rawMaterialId: "9179"},
{batchNo: "1233", location: "cvcvbc", qty: "200", rawMaterialId:"9169"},
{batchNo: "1266", location: "bnbn", qty: "600", rawMaterialId: "9935"}
   ]
```

**I have tried using For loops but not getting the expected output**

> Code which I tried

```
       for(int i=0; i<data.length;i++)
        {
         for(int j=0; i<data.length;i++)
          {
            if(data[i].rawMaterialId == data[j].rawMaterialId )
            {
                data[i].location=data[i].location +","+ data[j].location;
                data[i].batchNo=data[i].batchNo +"," + data[j].batchNo;
                data[i].quantity=data[i].quantity +"," + data[j].quantity;
            }
        } 
}
```

please help me out with this, any suggestions and corrections welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: int j = i + 1; do not start from beginning.

Comment: but after this also not able to get the expected output.Thanks, man  @yudongshen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have array *data* you can use stream api to transform it. At last line replace *Data* to real type of your items.

```
data = Arrays.stream(data).       // Create stream from your array
    collect(Collectors.toMap(     // Transform it to Map
        d -> d.rawMaterialId,     // It is keys of creating map
        d -> d,                   // This is values of creating map 
        (d1, d2) -> {             // Function for merging values with same keys. 
                                  // There happens all neded concatenations.
            d1.location = d1.location + "," + d2.location;
            d1.batchNo = d1.batchNo + "," + d2.batchNo;
            d1.quantity = d1.quantity + "," + d2.quantity;
            return d1;
        }).
    values().toArray(new Data[0]); // Transform map to new array. 
                                   // Replace Data to real type of your items.
```

Comment: I'm new to stream API, I'll try it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use map with key as rawMaterialId and value as list of data

```
Map<Integer,List<Data>> map= new HashMap<Integer,List<Data>>();
for(int i=0; i<data.length;i++)
{
if(map.contains(data[i].rawMaterialId))    {
   List<Data> list=map.get(data[i].rawMaterialId);
list.add(data[i]);
}
else    {
 List<Data> list=new ArrayList<Data>();
list.add(data[i]);
map.put(data[i]);
}
}
```

After this you can form the array you want by iterating over the map.

P.S: This is just a brief idea. Excuse me for the compilation errors(if any)

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].rawMaterialId == data[j].rawMaterialId ) {
                    // copy to new Data Array
            }
        }
    }
```